# Retirar uma parte da URL

Tags: javascript, regex

Tenho esta URL:

```
https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/
```

Como eu poderia retornar apenas `NormasDeProcedimento/` da URL com JavaScript e guardar numa variável? Sendo que o objetivo seria retirar o que estivesse do `Normativo/` para a frente até a próxima `/`.

Comment: Você tem que captura a url ou ela é estática?

Comment: Tenho este código para retirar `var str = window.location.href;`

Comment: Por retirar você quer dizer remover essa parte da string ou retornar apenas ela?

Comment: Neste caso seria retirar do "Normativo/" para a frente até a próxima "/" e ficaria neste caso "NormasDeProcedimentos/"

Comment: @fernandosavio Retornar apenas "NormasDeProcedimentos/"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Você pode usar expressões regulares para isolar parte da string usando [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const URL = "https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/"
const REGEX = /.*\/Normativo\/(.+?)\/.*/

console.log(URL.replace(REGEX, "$1"))
```

### Explicação:

Utilizo uma expressão regular para criar um grupo com a parte da string que vem depois de `/Normativo/` e depois substituo toda a string pelo conteúdo do grupo.

A regex:

```
.*\/Normativo\/(.+?)\/.*
```

- [`.*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk): Casará com qualquer caractere 0 a N vezes;
- `\/Normativo\/`: Casará com a string `/Normativo/`
- [`()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#grouping-back-references): Cria um grupo
- [`.+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus): Casará com qualquer caractere 1 a N vezes;
- [`?`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark): Torna o quantificador `+` [*non greedy*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-questionmark) (casará com a menor ocorrência possível)

Ou seja, da URL:

```
https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/
```

As partes da Regex que casarão serão:

- [`.*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk): `https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste`
- `\/Normativo\/`: `/Normativo/`
- [`(.+?)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-plus): `NormasDeProcedimentos` (Este valor é capturado em um grupo)
- [`\/.*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-asterisk): `/Documents/Histórico/`

Feito isso basta usar o [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) para substituir toda a string apenas pelo grupo capturado usando a notação `$n` onde `n` é o número do grupo capturado.

Como capturamos apenas um grupo na regex, então o número do grupo é 1 ([Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter)):

```
URL.replace(REGEX, "$1");
```

Answer (score 8):

Se precisar captura a `url` atual você deve usar o código `window.location.href`. Se for estática você pode fazer direto como no código abaixo, basta um simples `replace`.

```js
console.log(window.location.href)

let url = 'https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/'

url = url.replace('NormasDeProcedimentos/', '')
console.log(url)
```

Update:

Se deseja captura depois de `Normativo/` até a próxima `/` este regex basta: `(?<=Normativo\/)\w+\/`

## Explicando

- `(?<=)` Look behind positive, ou seja olhando pra trás, procure onde têm o texto `Normativo\/`
- `w+\/` procure por um texto seguido de uma barra.

Traduzindo: Encontre um texto com barra que seja precedido pela palavra `Normativo/`

```js
const expressao = /(?<=Normativo\/)\w+\//

let url = 'https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/'

let variavelCaptura = url.match(expressao)

url = url.replace(variavelCaptura, '')

console.log(url)
```

Compatibilidade do ***Look behind positive***:  http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/

Comment: Acho que você esqueceu de criar o grupo na regex, está dando erro quando executa.

Comment: @fernandosavio em qual exemplo? Pra mim funciona aqui

Comment: No segundo, dá um erro no console. Está rodando normal pra ti?

Comment: No Firefox da erro, no Chrome tá normal. Estranho...

Comment: @fernandosavio nem sabia que não estava funcionando no Firefox, vou dá uma olhada!

Comment: Look behind [só funciona em Chrome e Opera](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Browser_compatibility)... Aprendi mais uma coisa hoje  :)

Comment: @fernandosavio na verdade é só nas versões mais recentes, coloquei um link que mostra sua compatibilidade.

Comment: Não entendi, versões mais recentes do quê? O link que você mandou confirma o mesmo que eu mandei.. hahhaha

Answer (score 5):

Complementando as outras respostas, outra alternativa é:

```js
const url = "https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/";
const regex = /\/Normativo\/([^\/]+)/;

console.log(regex.exec(url)[1]); // NormasDeProcedimentos
```

O trecho `\/Normativo\/` verifica se existe a palavra "Normativo" entre duas barras.

Em seguida, eu uso `[^\/]+`:

- `[^\/]`: O `^` entre colchetes significa "qualquer caractere que não esteja dentro dos colchetes". No caso, só temos a barra (devidamente escapada com `\` para não ser confundida com os delimitadores da regex). Por isso, esta expressão significa "qualquer caractere que não seja `/`"
- o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+` significa: uma ou mais ocorrências.

Todo este trecho está entre parênteses para formar um [grupo de captura](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). E como é o primeiro par de parênteses, isso quer dizer que qualquer trecho será capturado no grupo 1.
Em seguida uso o [método `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec), que retorna o *match*, e pego a posição 1, que corresponde ao primeiro grupo de captura. O resultado será "NormasDeProcedimentos".

---

#### Indo um pouco além...

Usar `.+?` em vez de `[^\/]+` também funciona. Isso só começa a fazer alguma diferença se tivermos uma URL que não satisfaz a expressão.

Por exemplo, não ficou claro se a URL pode ser apenas: `https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos`

A expressão `.*\/Normativo\/(.+?)\/.*` faz com que uma barra seja obrigatória depois de `NormasDeProcedimentos`, então para a URL acima ela falharia. Só que `.+?` significa "uma ou mais ocorrências de **qualquer** caractere", sendo que o `?` significa "o mínimo de caracteres que satisfaça a expressão".

Isso quer dizer que a regex vai testar várias possibilidades antes de falhar (já que `.` significa "qualquer caractere", ou seja, há uma quantidade enorme de possibilidades a serem testadas).

Fiz um [teste desta regex no regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/94Burt/3/), e se você entrar no modo de *debug*, verá que a regex [vai e volta várias vezes na string](https://regex101.com/r/94Burt/3/debugger), verificando várias possibilidades em várias posições diferentes da mesma. [Nesta tela](https://regex101.com/r/94Burt/3/debugger) você pode usar o teclado (setas para a direita e esquerda para avançar e voltar, podendo ver o que a regex faz a cada passo). Quando aparecer uma seta vermelha apontando para a esquerda, isso representa um *backtracking*, ou seja, uma tentativa da regex voltar algumas posições da string e testar novas possibilidades.

[Neste mesmo link](https://regex101.com/r/94Burt/3/debugger), repare também do lado esquerdo: lá indica que a regex precisou de mais de 4500 passos até perceber que a string não satisfaz a expressão. Isso é graças ao `.+?`, e também por causa do `.*` no início e fim da expressão. Como o ponto significa "qualquer caractere", e os quantificadores `+` e `*` não tem um limite máximo, a regex tenta todas as possibilidades (com 1, 2, 3... n caracteres), até perceber que nenhum *match* pode ser encontrado.

Por outro lado, vamos ver o que acontece se usarmos `\/Normativo\/([^\/]+)\/` (repare que adicionei uma barra ao final, somente para que ela seja obrigatória e a regex falhe para a URL `https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos`).

[Coloquei-a também no regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Tozfjc/3/), e [veja que ela precisa de bem menos passos](https://regex101.com/r/Tozfjc/3/debugger) (cerca de 90) para perceber que não há um *match*. Isso porque retirei o `.*` do início e fim (pois eu só estou interessado no que tem depois de "/Normativo/"), e coloquei explicitamente o que eu quero (`[^\/]+` - tudo que não seja o caractere `/`).

Essa diferença acontece porque quantificadores preguiçosos (como o `.+?`), apesar de muito úteis para casos como esse, [têm o seu preço](http://rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#lazy_expensive). E usar ponto `.` é muito tentador, mas nem sempre é o que você precisa. O ponto significa "qualquer caractere", mas você não quer qualquer caractere, você quer "qualquer caractere **que não seja `/`**", então o melhor é sempre [dizer explicitamente o que quer e o que não quer](http://rexegg.com/regex-style.html#what_you_want).

**É claro que para programas pequenos, em que a regex executará poucas vezes, e principalmente para os casos em que é encontrado um *match*, a diferença de desempenho será irrelevante.** Mas é importante ter esses detalhes em mente, pois [há casos em que isso pode fazer diferença](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Além disso, vale lembrar que a quantidade exata de passos depende da engine e das strings de entrada. Mas a diferença entre as expressões permanece mais ou menos a mesma (a versão com `[^\/]` sempre será mais rápida que `.+?`).

---

#### Por que não validar a URL?

Já que a entrada é uma URL, você poderia usar o [objeto `URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) e obter somente o `pathname`:

```js
let url = 'https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/';
let path = new URL(url).pathname;

console.log(path); // "/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/"

// usar a regex com a string path (em vez de usar a URL inteira)
const regex = /\/Normativo\/([^\/]+)/;
console.log(regex.exec(path)[1]); // NormasDeProcedimentos
```

Com isso, você valida se a entrada é uma URL válida e ainda obtém uma string menor para a regex avaliar, fazendo com que ela execute um pouco mais rápido. Novamente, para poucas execuções, a diferença será irrelevante, mas pode ser que a validação feita por `new URL` valha a pena, pois aí você não aceita simplesmente qualquer string. Fica a seu critério usar ou não.

---

Na pergunta você disse que quer retornar `NormasDeProcedimento/` (com a barra no final). Sendo assim, basta você incluir esta barra na regex (e dentro dos parênteses, para que já fique disponível no grupo de captura).

```js
const url = "https://teste.teste.pt/sites/teste/Normativo/NormasDeProcedimentos/Documents/Histórico/";
const regex = /\/Normativo\/([^\/]+\/)/;

console.log(regex.exec(url)[1]); // NormasDeProcedimentos/
```

Comment: Sabia que você ia escrever uma resposta debugando a regex! +1 :)

Comment: @fernandosavio Poxa, estou ficando tão previsível assim? :-)

Comment: Depois de frequentar o site com frequência dá pra saber a área de mais domínio da galera e ver quando alguém tá coçando o dedo pra postar. Hahahaha